# C#: How to invoke multiple 'for loops' efficiently

Tags: c#, loops

Using C# as my language i need to create multiple for loops that utilize arrays with strings.  I might even be using 10's of for loops in my code but i know there is a better way of running multiple for loops without writing 50 for loops manually, what could be the shortcut,

** what i want to accomplish:
i want to print array[] in a series of possibilities, all the possibilities of array[], for example: array[0], array[0] array[1], array[0] array[1] array[2], etc. i want a little program that prints all the combinations in an array

here's my inefficient code:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "and", "nand", "not", "or", "nor", "xor" };

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
        {
            string test = array[i];

            Debug.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            string test = array[i];

            Debug.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            string test = array[i];

            Debug.WriteLine(array[i]);
        }
```

How do i shorten this so that i run x number of 'for loops'? in this case there are 3 for loops that need to be turned into 1 big for loop?  Do for loop x number of times.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I doubt your code here fully demonstrates what you're trying to achieve.  As it is, I'd say put the loop in a method and call it 3 times.  I don't think that's what you mean, though

Comment: i want to print array[] in a series of possibilities, all the possibilities of array[], for example: array[0], array[0] array[1], array[0] array[1] array[2], etc.  i want a little program that prints all the combinations in an array

Comment: Either of the answers below should do for you then

Comment: @adanrules: But where do you want to stop printing all these possibilities?  At array[0]...array[last]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

```
string[] array = new string[] { "and", "nand", "not", "or", "nor", "xor" };

for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < i;  j++)
    {
        Debug.Write(array[j]);
    }
    Debug.WriteLine();
}
```

This will print:

```
and
and nand
and nand not
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *nested for loops*:

```
int n = 3; // how many times you want to run it for
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) 
     {
         string test = array[i];

         Debug.WriteLine(array[i]);
     }
}
```

To improve the code further, you don't even need `string test = array[i];` and you can use a `foreach` loop like Blindy's answer

Comment: Efficiency might mean in terms of time to develop this.

Comment: It depends on your definition of efficiency, the OP appears to mean efficient in terms of writing, not in terms of performance, although clarification would be nice

Answer (score 2):

You mean like:

```
for(int repeat=0; repeat<3; ++repeat)
    for(int i=0; i<array.Length; ++i)  
        Debug.WriteLine(array[i]);
```

Or even better, no clunky indexing:

```
for(int repeat=0; repeat<3; ++repeat)
    foreach(var line in array)
        Debug.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question would be more efficiently written as

```
using System.Linq;

var strings = new[] { "and", "nand", "not", "or", "nor", "xor" };

foreach (var s in strings.Repeat(3).SelectMany(s => s)) 
{
    Debug.WriteLine(s);
}
```

---

if the loops don't interact and the actual order of execution is not important, and if the activity is complicated enough you could do something like this,

```
var loops = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).Select(i =>
   {
       foreach (var s in strings)
       {
           Debug.WriteLine(s);
       }

       Task.FromResult(true);
   });

Task.WhenAll(loops).Wait();
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to use this solution in my own code.

Answer (score -1):

Following only the information from your post, this is the code that you want

```
public void Strange(string[] array)
{
    Debug.Assert(array.Length > 1);
    for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        foreach (var item in array.Take(i))
            Debug.WriteLine(item);
}
```

But it won't provide combinations like `array[0], array[2], array[3], etc.` (jumping `array[1]`).